# Upsert with a missing not null column

Tags: sql, postgresql

So I am trying to do an upsert on a table that has a name field. This field is set to NOT NULL. When i do the upsert im only really concerned with updating an enabled column. My query comes to :

```
INSERT INTO products (id,enabled) 
VALUES (7260,false)
ON CONFLICT (id) 
DO UPDATE SET enabled = EXCLUDED.enabled RETURNING id
```

But im getting an error: ERROR: null value in column "name" violates not-null constraint

The NOT NULL violation comes from the INSERT.

Is it possible to do an upsert like this when a not null column is not in the query?

UPDATE:

From the comments below, something like:

```
INSERT INTO v2.products (id,name, enabled) 
VALUES (7260,'Tester', true)
ON CONFLICT (id) 
DO UPDATE SET enabled = EXCLUDED.enabled RETURNING id
```

But that still doesnt work for me. I get no error but the entry in the table is not updating

Comment: Your INSERT does not provide a value for the `name` column. That's the cause of the error, not your update part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The not null columns should have a default value, else an error will occur when inserting the row.

Alternatively, specify a not-null value within the `insert` statement (which could be ignored in the `update set`)

Comment: Ive updated the original post with an updated query. It doesnt work for me. I get no error but its not updating the entry

Comment: @discodowney using your example with a specified `name`, the insert should work: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6mvEV1kpUm3pZePMftW8wq/0

Comment: It does work indeed work. it helps to run the query on the right database......Thanks